# How can I show all `dad`s and `son`s of a structured string?

Tags: javascript

I made this code entirely by myself because everybody who I asked for help would give answers that were misleading and not applicable to my project, anyway, I created a code to scan a stringified JSON, simplify it, and extract its `parents` and `children`, the problem is one of my `dad`s has a child within a child.

**I'll do my best to explain it as clear as I can**:

**My Tree:**

[image: heyhey]

**its structure is generated and printed:**

```
[
   {1[
      {2} 
      {3[ 
         {4}
        ]}
      {5}
     ]}

     {6[ 
        {7}
       ]}
]
```

**then it's organized and printed like this:**

Dad: 1 & Son: 2

Dad: 3 & Son: 4

Dad: 6 & Son: 7

**However, it's missing multiple `dad`s and `son`s, and it should be:**

Dad: 1 & Son: 2

Dad: 1 & Son: 3

Dad: 1 & Son: 5

Dad: 3 & Son: 4

Dad: 6 & Son: 7

**I know why it's not working, but I haven't found a way to do it**

Thanks for making so far, any help is appreciated.

**My Code:**

```js
 var data = '[{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child1","id":2},{"name":"child3","id":3,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":4}]},{"name":"child2","id":5}]},{"name":"node2","id":6,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child3","id":7}]}]';

 var node;
 var temp;

 function dadSon(a) {
     var each;
     var numb;

     a = '' + a;
     for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         each = a.substring(i, i+1);
         numb = isNaN(each);

         if (each == '[') {temp += '['}
         if (each == ']') {temp += ']'}
         if (each == '{') {temp += '{'}
         if (each == '}') {temp += '}'}

         if (each == '"') {
             if (a.substring(i, i + 5) === ('"id":')) {
                 temp += (a.substring(i + 5, i + 6));
             }
         }
     }
     temp = temp.replace('undefined','');
     for (var h = 0; h < temp.length; h++){
         each = temp.substring(h, h+1);
         if(each == '{' && (temp.substring(h+2, h+3)) == '['){
             node += '\nDad: '+temp.substring(h+1, h+2); 
         }
         if((temp.substring(h-1, h)) == '[' && each == '{' && (temp.substring(h+2, h+3)) == '}'){
             node += ' & Son: '+temp.substring(h+1, h+2);     
         }
         
         
     }
    node = node.replace('undefined','');     
 }

 dadSon(data);
 console.log(temp);
 console.log(node);
```

A more clear view of the JSON Object:

```
[{
    "name": "node1",
    "id": 1,
    "is_open": true,
    "children": [{
        "name": "child1",
        "id": 2
    }, {
        "name": "child3",
        "id": 3,
        "is_open": true,
        "children": [{
            "name": "child2",
            "id": 4
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "child2",
        "id": 5
    }]
}, {
    "name": "node2",
    "id": 6,
    "is_open": true,
    "children": [{
        "name": "child3",
        "id": 7
    }]
}]
```

Comment: You want to use a recursive function for this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not parsing JSON with JSON.parse or eval()?

Comment: @MinusFour yes, I want to do it as if it were string, I know how to do it as JSON

Comment: I think you are obviating part of the reason of why you would consider JSON by not using neither eval() or JSON.parse(). There's probably better string formats for what you are trying to do than JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse` and iterate the tree with a recursive function:

```
(function printDadSon(data, parent) {
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
    if(parent) console.log('Dad: ' + parent + ' & Son: ' + data[i].id);
    if(data[i].children) printDadSon(data[i].children, data[i].id);
  }
})(JSON.parse(data));
```

Comment: well, I'll surrender to JSON, Thanks for helping me +1